# Enabling propriety driver doesn't work

Tags: uefi, asus, secure-boot

When I enable a proprietary driver (NVidia), I'm asked to enter a password for UEFI Secure Boot that it say I will needed to enter again on reboot, but when I reboot it doesn't ask for anything and I end up in a degraded mode. Mucking around with `mokutil` seems to mostly generate error messages and it seems to be unable to do change any state or set a password.

I'm running a ASUS mobo.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working was to:

- go into the BIOS
- enter advanced mode (iirc F7)
- select the boot tab
- switch "OS Type" from "Windows" to "Other OS"

Save, exit, boot, ... and the problem seems to have gone away. It seems I'm running on the new driver, but I never did enter the password.